# T-SQL function for generating slugs?

Tags: t-sql, slug

Quick check to see if anyone has or knows of a T-SQL function capable of generating slugs from a given nvarchar input. i.e;

> "Hello World" > "hello-world"
>   "This is a test" > "this-is-a-test"

I have a C# function that I normally use for these purposes, but in this case I have a large amount of data to parse and turn into slugs, so it makes more sense to do it on the SQL Server rather than have to transfer data over the wire.

As an aside, I don't have Remote Desktop access to the box so I can't run code (.net, Powershell etc) against it

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
As per request, here's the function I generally use to generate slugs:

```
public static string GenerateSlug(string n, int maxLength)
{
    string s = n.ToLower();                
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-z0-9s-]", "");              
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[s-]+", " ").Trim();             
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length <= maxLength ? s.Length : maxLength).Trim();             
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"s", "-"); 
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your C# slug-generator function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I've come up with as a solution. Feel free to fix / modify where needed.

I should mention that the database I'm currently developing against is case insensitive hence the LOWER(@str).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GenerateSlug]
(   
    @str VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT
SET @str = LOWER(@str)
SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9a-z ]%',@str)
WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
BEGIN
SET @str = STUFF(@str,@incorrectCharLoc,1,'')
SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9a-z ]%',@str)
END
SET @str = REPLACE(@str,' ','-')
RETURN @str
END
```

Mention to: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-udf-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/ for the original code.

Comment: It should not be `'%[^0-9a-z] %'` but should be `'%[^0-9a-z- ]%'`

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`LOWER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx) and [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(origString), ' ', '-')
FROM myTable
```

For wholesale update of the column (the code sets the `slug` column according to the value of the `origString` column:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET slug = REPLACE(LOWER(origString), ' ', '-')
```

Comment: To properly slugify a unicode string you would need much more than this. At least all non-ascii characters should be dealt with.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but for future generation, I found one function that deals even with accents [here](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_slugify-tsql/):

```
CREATE function [dbo].[slugify](@string varchar(4000)) 
    RETURNS varchar(4000) AS BEGIN 
    declare @out varchar(4000)

    --convert to ASCII
    set @out = lower(@string COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS)

    declare @pi int 
    --I'm sorry T-SQL have no regex. Thanks for patindex, MS .. :-)
    set @pi = patindex('%[^a-z0-9 -]%',@out)
    while @pi>0 begin
        set @out = replace(@out, substring(@out,@pi,1), '')
        --set @out = left(@out,@pi-1) + substring(@out,@pi+1,8000)
        set @pi = patindex('%[^a-z0-9 -]%',@out)
    end

    set @out = ltrim(rtrim(@out))

   -- replace space to hyphen   
   set @out = replace(@out, ' ', '-')

   -- remove double hyphen
   while CHARINDEX('--', @out) > 0 set @out = replace(@out, '--', '-')

   return (@out)
END
```

Comment: Using `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS` to strips accents only works with varchar variables. If you try doing the same with nvarchar variable, nothing happens. If the input is nvarchar it will have to be explicetly converted to varchar at some point using `cast(@string as varchar)`. If you don't, the accents will stay where they are.

Comment: Additionally using the cast with specific length might be required as SQL Server seems to shorten your string if it's converted to `varchar` inside a `SELECT` statement. For example `cast(@string as varchar(500))`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation of Jeremy's response. This might not technically be slugifying since I'm doing a couple of custom things like replacing "." with "-dot-", and stripping out apostrophes. Main improvement is this one also strips out all consecutive spaces, and doesn't strip out preexisting dashes.

```
create function dbo.Slugify(@str nvarchar(max)) returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @IncorrectCharLoc int
    set @str = replace(replace(lower(@str),'.',' dot '),'''','')

    -- remove non alphanumerics:
    set @IncorrectCharLoc = patindex('%[^0-9a-z -]%',@str)
    while @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
    begin
        set @str = stuff(@str,@incorrectCharLoc,1,' ')
        set @IncorrectCharLoc = patindex('%[^0-9a-z -]%',@str)
    end
    -- remove consecutive spaces:
    while charindex('  ',@str) > 0
    begin
    set @str = replace(@str, '  ', ' ')
    end
    set @str = replace(@str,' ','-')
return @str
end
```

Comment: Very helpful.  Two things I noticed this script didn't handle were trailing (probably leading?) spaces inputs that ended with a closing paren left a trailing hyphen.  For the first, trim the input.  For the second, I'm not sure because a trailing hyphen might be on purpose...

Answer (score 3):

I took Jeremy's response a couple steps further by removing all consecutive dashes even after spaces are replaced, and removed leading and trailing dashes.

```
create function dbo.Slugify(@str nvarchar(max)) returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
    declare @IncorrectCharLoc int
    set @str = replace(replace(lower(@str),'.','-'),'''','')

    -- remove non alphanumerics:
    set @IncorrectCharLoc = patindex('%[^0-9a-z -]%',@str)
    while @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
    begin
        set @str = stuff(@str,@incorrectCharLoc,1,' ')
        set @IncorrectCharLoc = patindex('%[^0-9a-z -]%',@str)
    end

    -- replace all spaces with dashes
    set @str = replace(@str,' ','-')

    -- remove consecutive dashes:
    while charindex('--',@str) > 0
    begin
        set @str = replace(@str, '--', '-')
    end

    -- remove leading dashes
    while charindex('-', @str) = 1
    begin
        set @str = RIGHT(@str, len(@str) - 1)
    end

    -- remove trailing dashes
    while len(@str) > 0 AND substring(@str, len(@str), 1) = '-'
    begin
        set @str = LEFT(@str, len(@str) - 1)
    end
return @str
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Converts a title such as "This is a Test" to an all lower case string such
-- as "this-is-a-test" for use as the slug in a URL.  All runs of separators
-- (whitespace, underscore, or hyphen) are converted to a single hyphen.
-- This is implemented as a state machine having the following four states:
--
--     0 - initial state
--     1 - in a sequence consisting of valid characters (a-z, A-Z, or 0-9)
--     2 - in a sequence of separators (whitespace, underscore, or hyphen)
--     3 - encountered a character that is neither valid nor a separator
--
-- Once the next state has been determined, the return value string is
-- built based on the transitions from the current state to the next state.
--
-- State 0 skips any initial whitespace.  State 1 includes all valid slug
-- characters.  State 2 converts multiple separators into a single hyphen
-- and skips trailing whitespace.  State 3 skips any punctuation between
-- between characters and, if no additional whitespace is encountered,
-- then the punctuation is not treated as a word separator.
--
CREATE FUNCTION ToSlug(@title AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retval AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''; -- return value
    DECLARE @i AS INT = 1;                -- title index
    DECLARE @c AS CHAR(1);                -- current character
    DECLARE @state AS INT = 0;            -- current state
    DECLARE @nextState AS INT;            -- next state
    DECLARE @tab AS CHAR(1) = CHAR(9);    -- tab
    DECLARE @lf AS CHAR(1) = CHAR(10);    -- line feed
    DECLARE @cr AS CHAR(1) = CHAR(13);    -- carriage return
    DECLARE @separators AS CHAR(8) = '[' + @tab + @lf + @cr + ' _-]';
    DECLARE @validchars AS CHAR(11) = '[a-zA-Z0-9]';

    WHILE (@i <= LEN(@title))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @c = SUBSTRING(@title, @i, 1),

        @nextState = CASE
            WHEN @c LIKE @validchars THEN 1
            WHEN @state = 0 THEN 0
            WHEN @state = 1 THEN CASE
                WHEN @c LIKE @separators THEN 2
                ELSE 3 -- unknown character
                END
            WHEN @state = 2 THEN 2
            WHEN @state = 3 THEN CASE
                WHEN @c LIKE @separators THEN 2
                ELSE 3 -- stay in state 3
                END
            END,

        @retval = @retval + CASE
            WHEN @nextState != 1 THEN ''
            WHEN @state = 0 THEN LOWER(@c)
            WHEN @state = 1 THEN LOWER(@c)
            WHEN @state = 2 THEN '-' + LOWER(@c)
            WHEN @state = 3 THEN LOWER(@c)
            END,

        @state = @nextState,

        @i = @i + 1
    END
    RETURN @retval;
END
```

Comment: could you add more comments?

Answer (score 0):

```
To slug with Vietnamese unicode    

CREATE function [dbo].[toslug](@string nvarchar(4000)) 
    RETURNS varchar(4000) AS BEGIN 
    declare @out nvarchar(4000)
    declare @from nvarchar(255)
    declare @to varchar(255)
    --convert to ASCII dbo.slugify
    set @string = lower(@string)
    set @out = @string
    set @from = N'ýỳỷỹỵáàảãạâấầẩẫậăắằẳẵặéèẻẽẹêếềểễệúùủũụưứừửữựíìỉĩịóòỏõọơớờởỡợôốồổỗộđ·/_,:;'
    set @to = 'yyyyyaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeuuuuuuuuuuuiiiiioooooooooooooooood------'
    declare @pi int 
    set @pi = 1
    --I'm sorry T-SQL have no regex. Thanks for patindex, MS .. :-)
    while @pi<=len(@from) begin
        set @out = replace(@out, substring(@from,@pi,1), substring(@to,@pi,1))
        set @pi = @pi + 1
    end
    set @out = ltrim(rtrim(@out))

   -- replace space to hyphen   
   set @out = replace(@out, ' ', '-')

   -- remove double hyphen
   while CHARINDEX('--', @out) > 0 set @out = replace(@out, '--', '-')

   return (@out)
END
```

Comment: Please take a look at how your post has rendered, and [edit it to fix the formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42667458/edit). You get a handy little preview in the post-editing area so you can see what it's going to look like before you submit it.

Comment: This link may be useful to you - [answer]